# Creating relationship among records in subgrids in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have two subgrids

1. Parent
2. Children

Now I will be adding entries to it from the contact entity
What I want to achieve is, I want to create parent-child relationship among the data that are there in these two subgrids so that I can use it for querying in future

Usage scenario:

I have a entity form for a entity called as MedicalCase
MedicalCase form will have two subgrids for "Children" and "Parent"
Now I will be able to add children and parent records to subgrid from the Contact entity
For these records in the parent and children subgrid, I want to specify, which parent is the father/mother of which child
I don't have the luxury of editing the Contact records, is there any other means that you can think of?
Someway in which I can record the relationship between child and parent in the subgrids
Hope I am clear enough, feel free to ask me if you need any clarifications

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do the Parent records represent parents of the contact?  Or do they represent parents of Children records?

Comment: Does the Child form have a lookup to Parent?

Comment: @Polshgiant  Both the parent and children belong to Contact entity
I have created two views, one for parent and one for children
A record in Medical case will have two subgrids, one for parent and one for children
No child record is not having a lookup to parent

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding the situation exactly, but after several re-reads it sounds like you need a custom many-to-many relationship entity.  Create an entity called ChildParentRelationship (CPR) which should have a lookup to Child and a lookup to Parent.  Your Medical Case form should have a sub-grid for CPR entity.  When a user creates a new CPR record, they will specify the Child and Parent.  Does that get you what you need?